# Starting with Ruby on Rails and connecting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, connection

Basically, I have a ruby site which I need to make some amends on. Simple ones like changing title tags on pages. The site is on a dedicated server but I cannot work out how to connect up to the ruby site and start editing the files.

I have ruby installed but looking round I just get completely lost. Does anyone just have a simple step by step for connecting and getting the files or know of somewhere with this?

Edit: I can connect to the server with filezilla but if I edit a file and copy back to the server it does not seem to take effect?

Comment: Contact your server hosting company for info on how to connect...

Comment: This question needs to be more specific, provide details of what you have tried, and so on.

Comment: You can connect using FTP/SSH, or use a built-in editor, if the host provides one. Contact your host on how to get access to the FTP/SSH, then download [FileZilla](http://filezilla-project.org/) or something equivalent, and get started!

Comment: You need to restart the rails server for changes to be seen.  What type of web server is it running under (Apache, Nginx...), and what type of app server (Passenger, Unicorn...)?  If you're not sure, your hosting company can tell you this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need to overrite

PROJECTDIR/tmp/restart.txt

you can open tmp/restart.txt on your FTP server via any text editor and press Ctrl+S (save it), so file will be touched and server will be restarted

or if you have ssh access run

touch tmp/restart.txt from your rails app root

Comment: I found it seems to be cached on the website and that is why changes were not appearing. If we do a server restart it then accepts the changes. Thanks for your advice!